# imacros javascript wont loop through csv

Tags: javascript, csv, syntax, imacros

Ive just scripted an imacros in Javascript. The code works well in imacros but the loop  doesnt increment when running it via javascript. The following code keeps using the first row of the Datasource csv file.

```
macro += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + "\n";
macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\demo.csv" + "\n";
macro += "" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO={{!COL2}}" + "\n";
macro += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macro += "" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:deguy EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:idvenga EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\imacros FILE=results.csv" + "\n";
var n = 10;

for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
iimPlay(macro);
}
```

How can I make it loop through all the rows of the Datasource csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked as one had to take control of the loop variable

```
 macro += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + "\n";
 macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
 macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\demo.csv" + "\n";
 macro += "" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
 macro += "URL GOTO={{!COL2}}" + "\n";
 macro += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
 macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + "\n";
 macro += "" + "\n";
 macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:deguy EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
 macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:idvenga EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
 macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\imacros FILE=results.csv" + "\n";


 for (var i=1;i<10;i++)
 {

 iimSet("i",i)
 iimPlay(macro)
 }
```